# Does an oscillating sequence always diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Below is the example I'm working on:[<sup>1)</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZTVZ.png)

$$ a_n = \frac{(-1)^n n^2}{2n^2 + 5}. $$

*For the example:* I know that $(-1)^n$ will make the sequence oscillate
and I know that $n\to\infty$ will, along with L'Hôpital's, make $\frac{n^2}{2n^2 + 5}$ converge to $\frac{1}{2}$. Since $(a_n)$ oscillates, it'll never converge, which means it'll diverge.

I'm wondering if this is correct and if this means that every oscillating sequence diverges. I checked online and they say that oscillating sequences don't converge or diverge which is confusing me more. Thanks for any help given.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: Often people call a sequence *oscillating* if it neither converges nor diverges either to $+\infty$ or to $-\infty$. (Alternatively, a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ is said to be oscillating if it does not have a limit in the extended real number line $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=[-\infty,\infty]$.) And it is true that if $(a_n)$ is alternating and $|a_n|\to\ell>0$, then $(a_n)$ oscillates.

Comment: A useful fact is that a sequence $(a_n)_n$ converges to a iff $\{n: |a-a_n|<r\}$ is finite for every (any) $r>0.$ You seem to be confused about the definition(s) of "oscillating sequence".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of an oscillate sequence which also converge: $\lim_{n\to \infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{n}{n^{2}+2} = 0$

Comment: Why not just $(-1)^n/n$?